# install algs4 on windows - to use in atom?

Tags: java, atom-editor

I am trying to use libraries from princeton algorithm in my pc and use it with atom.
I have followed the steps up to the point where I have added the classpath on my UserVariable and next command is to download jar file in %SystemRoot%\Sun.. directory. But I have no idea how to get in that directory!! And I am pretty sure I need to add the variable on atom as well so that I can just use package edu.princeton.algs4.jar to compile and run the codes.

Can someone provide me some help with it?

Answer (score 0):

Atom does not have any ability to run code or any idea of what to do with libraries. What's important is that your `javac` binary knows how to find the library. If the compiler knows where to look, then any Atom package you use will work just fine.